# How do you change the label text for a GTK toggle button?

Tags: c, gtk

I have a gtk toggle button which I set a label inside as in:

`prog_list[i].drawn_w = gtk_toggle_button_new_with_label( btn_name );`

I need to be able to modify the label text info on the button later in program execution.  Is this possible?

thx.
/w

Answer (score 1):

From the [doc](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkButton.html)

```
void
gtk_button_set_label (GtkButton *button,
                      const gchar *label);
```

So you would use it by

```
gtk_button_set_label (GTK_BUTTON (prog_list[i].drawn_w), "new Text");
```

This function is in the button class, which is a parent to the toggle button class. Meaning any function you see in the  button class you can use in the toggle button class. (See "[Object Hierarchy](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkToggleButton.html#GtkToggleButton.object-hierarchy)")

Comment: For what it's worth GTK+ provides function-like macros that reduce the number of explict casts you need while providing runtime type checking; in this case it would be `GTK_BUTTON(prog_list[i].drawn_w)`.